# What is the term for making a cross in the air (like when passing a cemetery)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for making a cross with your hands in the air? It's a four point motion that goes from head to chest, then shoulder to shoulder.

An example situation where someone does this might be a funeral procession passing by.

Comment: Related, [Roses are red, bananas are yellow](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4306/roses-are-red-apples-are-green).

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Oh, sorry. I'm not a regular here. I wasn't sure if these were allowed or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb is cross and you "cross yourself." I hope that makes it clear.

> cross
>     v.tr.
>    6. To make the sign of the cross upon or over as a sign of devotion.

Answer (score 5):

[Sign of the Cross](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/13785a.htm)

> A term applied to various manual acts, liturgical or devotional in character, which have this at least in common: that by the gesture of tracing two lines intersecting at right angles they indicate symbolically the figure of Christ's cross.
>
> Most commonly and properly the words "sign of the cross" are used of
>   the large cross traced from forehead to breast and from shoulder to
>   shoulder, such as Catholics are taught to make upon themselves when
>   they begin their prayers,

Comment: But the verb is [*to cross yourself/oneself*](http://www.wikihow.com/Cross-Yourself)

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_of_the_Cross

Comment: @Jim It's also possible to use the verb, make, as in: *"He made the sign of the cross."*

Answer (score 1):

You might use "bless" as a verb.

One of the definitions or example of "bless" given at https://www.google.fr/search?q=define%3Abless is ...

> - make the sign of the cross.
>     "the poor parson, blessing himself, brought up the rear"

It might (I don't know) be Roman Catholic usage, to so associate "the sign of the cross" with the act of "blessing".

Anyway, if a priest "blesses" you I think that's likely to involve the sign of the cross.

But as the accepted answer says, you're also taught to "cross yourself" e.g. in church.